# Binding Dictionary<string,List<Class>> to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have collection

```
Dictionary<string, List<Manager>> Stuff;
```

Manager is class with some properties.
I would like to bind this dictionary to TreeView or ListView like this:

Key as title, then list of Managers as children. For example:

- Director (it's key from dictionary)

  - John (it's property Manager.Name)
  - Steve
- Owner

  - Jack

I tried something like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

It shows me titles but I don't know how to make it further.
Or maybe it will be better to change collection and bind it in some other way.

EDIT

I unnecessarily complicated job with this dictionary. I created a class `Stuff` with property `string Name;`, and `List<Managers> Managers;`.
Use it in main class as `ObservableCollection<Stuff> Stuff;` and it works fine with this XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Managers}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So yeah using Dictionary wasn't best in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

However, I'd always recommend using an `ObservableCollection<CustomDataType>` as the `ItemsSource` because it just makes the whole job simpler. For more help with the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, please see the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: It dont work, it also shows me only Keys without values but nvm. I edited my post.